# Pass Javascript values from view to controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, stripe-payments

I am in the process of setting up stripe subscription plan within my app. According to stripe documentation I must do a javascript call to create a paymethod.

```html
var form = document.getElementById('subscription-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  // We don't want to let default form submission happen here,
  // which would refresh the page.
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createPaymentMethod({
    type: 'card',
    card: cardElement,
    billing_details: {
      email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
    },
  }).then(stripePaymentMethodHandler);
});
```

I then have to publish the paymethods to my server(controller). I am new to javascript and wondering how I can get the variable "results" from the below code to my controller?

```html
function stripePaymentMethodHandler(result, email) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Show error in payment form
  } else {
    // Otherwise send paymentMethod.id to your server
    fetch('/create-customer', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
        payment_method: result.paymentMethod.id
      }),
    }).then(function(result) {
     return result.json();
    }).then(function(customer) {
      // The customer has been created
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the variable `result` not `results`. Also, it's not clear what you mean by "my controller." Are you asking how to send a request to your server?

Comment: Yes result. Yes, send result variable to my server. I need this so I can submit Customer Creation portion next, but that must be done on my mvc Controller on the server.

Comment: You can use the `fetch` function to send requests. Before we can give you anything more specific, we'd need more details on your controller. Do you already have a controller route that receives the result?

Comment: My controller is called "Subscriptions" and I have a Create method in the subscriptions controller. With the Fetch function I would love to know how that works on sending it to my controller "subscriptions". What other information would you need?

Comment: I'd suggest posting your controller code. Without that, we don't know the shape of the data that needs to be sent to the controller, which HTTP method it is, what the URL route is, etc.

Comment: So I guess that is my question. What is standard method for this?

Comment: Right now, you're passing email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com', payment_method: 'pm_xxx' to your server route at /create-customer.  guessing you need to either handle that or include more data when passing to your server